# how to groupby and sum multiple columns in pandas without listing them all

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

**Background**

I've got a dataframe with 100 columns, basically ['Year', 'month', 'a', 'b', 'c'...]

```
Year    Month   a   b   c   d   e
2012    Jan    74   67  22  51  90
2012    Feb    100  2   46  75  1
2013    Mar    47   38  52  91  63
2013    Apr    52   83  34  59  44
```

**Problem**

I want to group by year and sum all the values, but I don't know how to do it without listing them all. like below;

```
          a  b   c    d   e
2012    174  69 68  126  91
2013     99 121 86  150 107
```

**What I've tried**

I've converted my columns to a list, and tried to feed that into the groupby function, but no luck

```
headers = list(df.iloc[:, 2:100].columns)
print(headers)

sum_df = df.groupby(['Year']).sum(headers)
```

**Help requested**

Anyone know a easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `select_dtypes`:

```
>>> df.select_dtypes('number').groupby('Year', as_index=False).sum()

   Year    a    b   c    d    e
0  2012  174   69  68  126   91
1  2013   99  121  86  150  107
```

**Update**

You can also use `numeric_only=True` as parameter of `sum`:

```
>>> df.groupby('Year', as_index=False).sum(numeric_only=True)
   Year    a    b   c    d    e
0  2012  174   69  68  126   91
1  2013   99  121  86  150  107
```